# How can I visualize a color mapping?

Tags: python

I have a function [image] which takes a color in RGB format as input and outputs a color in RGB format. It is guaranteed to be differentiable, but nothing else.  For simplicity, lets say it would just change the order of channels:

```
def f(r, g, b):
    return b, g, r
```

Now I would like to visualize this by plotting two color bars like this:

[image]

However, I have two problems with this:

1. I don't know how to implement this (so: what is a reasonable way to interact with a canvas? matplotlib?)
2. I'm not too sure if this color bar is appropriate. Two color wheels which are inside of each other might be better? Two color triangles next to each other?

Answer (score 0):

A different way of going about the colormaps than the rgb method is to use the matplotlib color maps, available [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import linspace

sample_data = [1,5,10,20,45,50] ## y-values

def clr_map(max_index):
    cmap = plt.get_cmap('plasma')
    ## limits of cmap are (0,1) 
    ## ==> use index within (0,1) for each color 
    clrs = [cmap(i) for i in linspace(0, 1, max_index)] 
    return clrs

def clr_plot(data_list):
    clrs = clr_map(len(data_list)) ## call function above
    clr_list = [clr for clr in clrs]
    x_loc = [val+1 for val in range(max(data_list))] ## x-values of barplot
    ## use range for efficiency with multiple overlays
    plt.bar(x_loc[0], data_list[0], label='bar 1', color=clr_list[0])
    plt.bar(x_loc[1], data_list[1], label='bar 2', color=clr_list[1])
    plt.bar(x_loc[2], data_list[2], label='bar 3', color=clr_list[2])
    plt.bar(x_loc[3], data_list[3], label='bar 4', color=clr_list[3])
    plt.bar(x_loc[4], data_list[4], label='bar 5', color=clr_list[4])
    plt.bar(x_loc[5], data_list[5], label='bar 6', color=clr_list[5])
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()

clr_plot(sample_data)
```